# Is there a way to print integers at one shot through the int pointer?

Tags: c++, c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
 int integers[40] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,-1};
 int integers1[40];
 int *ptr;
 int *ptr1;

 ptr = integers;
 ptr1 = integers1;


 while(*ptr != -1){
  *ptr1++ = *ptr++;
 }
 *ptr1 = -1;

 ptr1 = integers1;
 while(*ptr1 != -1){
  printf("\n *ptr1 : %d \n",*ptr1);
  *ptr1++;
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to print the integers pointed by ptr1 at one shot without using the loop ?

**EDITED:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
 char integers[40] = {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','\0'};
 char integers1[40];
 char *ptr;
 char *ptr1;

 ptr = integers;
 ptr1 = integers1;


 while(*ptr != '\0'){
  *ptr1++ = *ptr++;
 }
 *ptr1 = -1;

 ptr1 = integers1;
 ptr = integers;

 printf("\n *ptr1 : %s  \n",ptr1);
 printf("\n ptr : %s \n",ptr);

 return 0;
}
```

The last integer 10 is not getting printed . Instead its getting printed as 0. Why is it printing with a diff value? . If I replace with the value 9, it gets displayed correctly. for 10 and above integers its printing the 1st digit leaving the second digit behind.

Comment: What do you mean by one shot?  Do you mean all at once?

Comment: no. there's no `%everything` formatting code for that.

Comment: put them in char array(convert them to chars). then print as string.

Comment: as we print all the strings through %s

Comment: @Angus no there is no such format string available in C, if you wants this work  repeatedly I suggest you to write a function (may be a macro)

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik that wouldn't have the same result. A `char`-array with values `1`, `2` etc isn't printed the same as printing an array of `int`s. Plus `%s` expects the array to be 0-terminated, which this array isn't.

Comment: @Gireesh : You are correct. I need to write a macro function

Comment: @huseyin : I tried as you told. I'm getting warnings as well as the array doesnt hold good for integers more than two digits

Comment: Also your `char integers[] = { .... '10' ... };` may be problematic unless `char` is guaranteed to handle multi-byte character literals - it most likely isn't...

Answer (score 7):

No there isn't. There's a good reason too: unlike `char*` there isn't a well defined meaning for "end of a sequence of `int`s" and an `int*` doesn't know the how many `int`s it's pointing to.

With a `char*` we have `'\0'`, if you forget this, then stuff like `printf("%s", cptr)` will break. With an `int*` we don't have a nice equivalent since people use `0` quite a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Not in [c](/questions/tagged/c). But as your question is also tagged [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)...

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <algorithm>

#define SIZE 40

void my_print(int i) { std::printf("%d\n", i); }

int main()
{
  int integers[SIZE] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,-1};
  int* end = std::find(integers, integers + SIZE, -1);
  std::for_each(integers, end, my_print);
}
```

In C++11 you can replace `my_print` with a lambda if you want.